# Application insights and custom properties of Exception

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I have the following exception:

```
public class InvalidStatusCodeException : Exception
{
    public HttpStatusCode ReceivedStatusCode { get; set; }
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }

    public InvalidStatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode receivedStatusCode, string apiUrl)
    {
        ReceivedStatusCode = receivedStatusCode;
        ApiUrl = apiUrl;
    }
}
```

throw it in some cases:

```
        string url = "api/group/1/getAll";
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new InvalidStatusCodeException(response.StatusCode, url);
```

if I catch and log this exception:

```
        catch(InvalidStatusCodeException status_ex)
        {
            string error = $"Invalid Status code for request: '{status_ex.ApiUrl}', received code: {status_ex.ReceivedStatusCode}";
            log.LogError(status_ex, error, "InvalidStatusCode");
        }
```

I don't see values of my custom properties (ReceivedStatusCode, ApiUrl) and can see details only in error message.

[image]

If I don't catch this exception at all and exception is being logged automatically then no way to see details at all.

Any way to see these custom properties without additional catching of exception?

Comment: "I don't see values of my custom properties" don't see them where? Watch window? Debug window? output?

Comment: @Charlieface added

Comment: @OlegSh, you can also consider using [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#logging-scopes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the concept of structure logging which logs the named constant as custom properties.

```
catch(InvalidStatusCodeException status_ex)
{
     log.LogError(status_ex, "Invalid Status code for request: '{ApiUrl}', received code: {ReceivedStatusCode}", status_ex.ApiUrl, status_ex.ReceivedStatusCode);
 }
```

The above log will add `ApiUrl` and `ReceivedStatusCode` as custom properties in application insights log.

**Update**

You don't need to throw and catch the exception. You can log in the else block of `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` like shown below:

```
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
     
 }
 else
 {
     log.LogError(status_ex, "Invalid Status code for request: '{ApiUrl}', received code: {ReceivedStatusCode}",
         apiUrl, response.StatusCode);
 }
```

Other way of logging custom properties is via Logging Scope  (check [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Functions/Triggers/Http/ToDoItemsController.cs#L33)) and via TelemetryInitializer (check [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Infrastructure/ApplicationInsightsInitializers/CorrelationTelemetryInitializer.cs))

Comment: I used the same approach, but first at all, custom properties are not saved (only as message string) and, secondly, I have to catch and rethrow this exception

Comment: @OlegSh - I you notice, in the `LogError`, string interpolation is **not** used. The variables are passed as arguments and `{}` contains the string literal and those will be logged as custom properties. Have you used the same approach?

Comment: yes, you are right. But I would like to avoid catch error at all and write custom properties. Is it possible?

Comment: As such you don't need to throw the exception. You can add the log in the else condition of ` if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` code condition. The other way of logging the custom properties are `Logging Scope` (check [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Functions/Triggers/Http/ToDoItemsController.cs#L33)) and via `TelemetryInitializer` (check [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Infrastructure/ApplicationInsightsInitializers/CorrelationTelemetryInitializer.cs))

Comment: Another approach is to use `DelegatingHandler` to log the entry while sending request and receiving response. Check the sample implementation at [here](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Infrastructure/DelegatingHandlers/HeaderLoggingDelegatingHandler.cs).

Comment: thank you for such careful explanation and good examples. In any case, no way to say App Insights to log custom fields automatically :(

Comment: IMO, this solution doesn't scale. I don't want to have to manually log every exception, or provide a specific logging statement for each exception type.

Answer (score 1):

Add a message to the base `Exception`

```cs
public class InvalidStatusCodeException : Exception
{
    public HttpStatusCode ReceivedStatusCode { get; set; }
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }

    public InvalidStatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode receivedStatusCode, string apiUrl) 
        : base($"Invalid Status code for request: '{apiUrl}', received code: {receivedStatusCode}")
    {
        ReceivedStatusCode = receivedStatusCode;
        ApiUrl = apiUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: probably, it's a solution. But I want to save on App Insights custom properties in anyway and don't want to prepare message on exception level (no way to sorting/filtering, can be localization etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for this. There are 3 steps:

- create your custom telemetry middleware, which specifies what you want to capture from the request
- register it as a middleware extension
- register your middleware to be used by your server.

Step 1: Customise what telemetry you want to capture:

```
public class CustomTelemetryMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomTelemetryMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    // https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/686#issuecomment-530353448
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = context.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
        if (requestTelemetry != null)
        {
            var request = context.Request;

            // add items to show up in Request Properties:
            requestTelemetry.Context.User.Id = context.User.Identity.Name;

            // add items to show up in Custom Properties:
            requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("PayingCustomer", "Yes");

            /* Capture the request body as a Custom Property
             */
            if (request?.Body?.CanRead == true)
            {
                request.EnableBuffering();

                var bodySize = (int)(request.ContentLength ?? request.Body.Length);
                if (bodySize > 0)
                {
                    request.Body.Position = 0;
                    byte[] body;
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bodySize))
                    {
                        await request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
                        body = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                    request.Body.Position = 0;

                    var requestBodyString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("RequestBody", requestBodyString);
                }
            }
        }
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Step 2, register it:

```
public static class CustomTelemetryMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomTelemetry(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CustomTelemetryMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

And finally, Step 3, register it in your Startup.cs

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
{
  // put this towards the end of your pipeline
  app.UseCustomTelemetry();
}
```