# Azure Function exception logging to application insight

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Logging to application insight when there is an exception in an Azure function project but only exception message is logged, I want to add custom property

Comment: Do you track the exception manually?

Comment: @PeterBons no it logs automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
catch(InvalidStatusCodeException status_ex)
{
     log.LogError(status_ex, "Invalid Status code for request: '{ApiUrl}', received code: {ReceivedStatusCode}", status_ex.ApiUrl, status_ex.ReceivedStatusCode);
 }
```

The above log will add ApiUrl and ReceivedStatusCode as custom properties in application insights log.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65502187/1384539